# How to use one list in different functions, Python

Tags: python, list

So I do not want to use global variables, and I have a list that I want to use i different functions. How do I do it?

I got this so far:

```
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myList = list()

def func1():
    l = List()
    l.myList.append(22)

def func2():
    l.myList.append(34)
```

I get an error when executing the second function and the question is how I continue to put elements into myList using different functions.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you pass it as arguments to the functions?

Comment: I guess this is just for demonstration, but the class here adds nothing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the list as an argument to the two functions:

```
def func1(l):
    l.myList.append(22)

def func2(l):
    l.myList.append(34)

def driver():
    l = List()
    func1(l)
    func2(l)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was heplful, little late though. Better late than never right.:)

Answer (score 0):

`l object` created in `finc1`:

```
l = List()
```

So, it's local. You should consider scope of variables and objects.